# Noether current Lorentz rotation massive vector field

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, angular-momentum, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, noethers-theorem

I'm considering a massive vector field in classical field theory.

With the Lagrangian density
$$\mathscr{L}=-\frac{1}{4}V^{\mu\nu}V_{\mu\nu}+\frac{1}{2}m^2V^{\mu}V_{\mu}.$$
I want to prove from the Lorentz rotational generators that the Noether current is:
$$J^{\mu}_{(\rho\sigma)}=(x_{\rho}T^{\mu}_{\sigma}-x_{\sigma}T^{\mu}_{\rho})+(V^{\mu}_{\rho}V_{\sigma}-V_{\mu}^{\sigma}V_{\rho})=L_{\rho\sigma}+S_{\rho\sigma}.$$
I have some problems getting the term spin $S_{\rho\sigma}$.